# flycheck & auctex: Hide an specific warning

Tags: auctex, flycheck

When using Auctex with Flycheck (`Chktex`) I get hundreds of warnings of the kind

```
 some.tex   321   8 warning  3  You should enclose the previous parenthesis with `{}'. (tex-chktex)
```

How I can disable this specific kind of error for being reported?

Comment: You can ignore the warnings with the custom variable flycheck-error-list-minimum-level setting it to a higher level.

Comment: Yes, but that would remove useful errors too.  Is there no way to blacklist `ID =3` ?

Comment: Where is `flycheck-error-list-minimum-level` located how can I make changes on it? @f-sasa

Comment: @alper it is located in the file  flycheck,el line 804, you can change it with the customize emacs feature M-x customize-variable RET flycheck-error-list-minimum-level , make sure you have flycheck loaded with (require 'flycheck)

Comment: I find it but I am unable to change a specific warning please see => https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58798/how-to-disable-specific-flycheck-warning-messages-in-latex-mode  @f-sasa

Comment: Please see [this answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641076/chktex-wrong-length-of-dash-may-have-been-used-8/641217#641217) for all the ways to suppress certain warnings. In this case, I think what you want is to add `--nowarn 3` to the `CmdLine` section of your `chktexrc` file.