# How to disable specific flycheck-warning messages in LaTeX-mode?

Tags: latex, flycheck

Currenty I am on LaTeX-mode-hook using `flycheck`.

```
(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(require 'tex)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
  ))

(setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil
      ispell-local-dictionary "en_US"
      ispell-program-name "aspell"
      ispell-extra-args '("--sug-mode=ultra"))

(dolist (hook '(text-mode-hook))
     (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode 1))))
    (dolist (hook '(change-log-mode-hook log-edit-mode-hook))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (flyspell-mode -1))))
```

---

For example I am getting following `flycheck-warning` message when I write `function()` into my `.tex` file:

`You should put a space in front of parenthesis. [36]`

**[Q]** Is there any way to ignore specific `flycheck-warning` messages?

Comment: Please see [this answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641076/chktex-wrong-length-of-dash-may-have-been-used-8/641217#641217) for all the ways to suppress certain warnings. In this case, I think what you want is to add `--nowarn 36` to the `CmdLine` section of your `chktexrc` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't disable warning messages at the `flycheck` level; you disable them using the underlying checker, which in your case for `latex-mode` is `chktex`.  One can find the underlying checker by running `M-x flycheck-describe-checker RET`.

The `chktex` [manual](https://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf) explains how to do per line suppression by adding a case-insensitive comment to the end your line `% chktex ##` where `##` is the error number.  In your case you would add `% chktex 36`.

Comment: Should I add `% chktex 36` into each line I don't want flyspell activated?

Comment: Not quite.  The error code 36 is specific to neglecting to put a space in front of the parenthesis.  Not all lines will have an error code of 36, because `chktex` might warn you about other things.  Generally the idea behind linters like `chktex` is they tell you "hey, you might be doing something wrong" and you adding that comment tells `chktex` "thanks for the warning, but I'm doing this intentionally."  You can disable a particular code for the whole file using `% chktex-file 36` or in a chktexrc configuration file as explained in the manual linked above.

Comment: Cool adding `% chktex-file 36` actually suppress all the warning messages in the complete latex file

Comment: Is it also possible to completely disable `chktex` in the buffer?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521016/10602009